# How to use has_scope gem in a view in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-scope

I'm trying to add a clickable link that will sort a page of links alphabetically using has_scope gem. What exactly would i put in my view to make this work?

**Model  Links.rb**

```
 scope :abc, -> { order("links.title ASC") }
```

**Links_Controller.rb**

```
 has_scope :abc

 def index
    @links = apply_scopes(Link).all
 end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div id="links-wrapper">
    <%= render partial: "shared/link", collection: @links %>
</div>
```

**_link.html.erb**

```
<div class="link">

    <a class="link-title" href="<%= link.url %>" target="_blank"><%= link.title %></a>


    <div class="link-printed-url"><%= link.url %></div>

    <p class="link-description"><%= link.description %></p>

    <div class="link-tags">
        <% link.tags.any? %>
            <% link.tags.each do |tag| %>
                <span class="label-tag">
                    <%= link_to tag_path(tag) do %>
                        #<%= tag.name %>
                    <% end %>
                </span>     
        <% end %>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a title param to the scope.

Change the scope in the model to `scope :abc, -> title { order("links.title ASC") }`

or

`scope :abc, -> title { order(title: :asc) }`

You could do something like this in the partial

```
  <div class="link">
    <a class="link-title" href="<%= link.url %>" target="_blank"><%= link.title %></a>


    <div class="link-printed-url"><%= link.url %></div>

    <p class="link-description"><%= link.description %></p>

  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="link-tags">
    <%= link_to 'Order ASC', tag_path(:abc => true) %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since has_scope works off of url params you will need to add the params on a link_to

```
<%= link_to "title", links_path(abc: true) %>
```

Comment: I get wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) for  scope :abc, -> { order("links.title ASC") }